# Rhyming Riddle: To choose, to crack, a nose, a name

Tags: riddle, rhyme

To choose, to crack, a nose, a name.

To play, to pluck, not just a game.

A colour, a car, any selection.

A politician at the election.

*This one's maybe a bit too easy?...*

**But think anyway, What could I be?**

Comment: edited to make what could I be rhyme :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> pick.

All of the things in the poem are

> synonyms of pick (to choose, to crack, to pluck, any selection...) or things that you can pick (a nose, a name, a colour, a politician in the election...).

Comment: Spot on, was it a little bit too easy? :P

Comment: I think all the synonyms made it easy to identify. Maybe focusing on the second type of clue would have made it harder.